# MySQL records that matches multiple criterias

Tags: mysql, sql

There is probably a simple answer to this but I can't seem to find it anywhere..

My table looks like this:

```
item_id     tag_id
----------------------
100          55
101          55
100         320
102         320
100          77
100         489
101         200
```

Asking for items with tags 55 AND 320 should return item_id = 100 (but not 101 or 102 as they don't have both tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM tab_name
WHERE tag_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3614a/1/0)**</kbd>

or even:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM tab_name
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id ORDER BY tag_id ) = '1,2';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3614a/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but I probably didn't explain this properly..There can be many tags ids not just 2..
Please check my edited question.

Comment: Actually this works, I see what you mean I just need to keep track of the number of tags provided. Thanks this is i great!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM table_name
WHERE tag_id IN (55,320)
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) > 1;
```

It will return item_id that have more than one distinct tag_id.

Pass your tags in IN by comma separated as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks but I don"t need items with more than 1 tag but items that contains tags exactly provided. See my edited post

Comment: Are you saying you will pass these two tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id
  FROM Table1
  WHERE tag_id IN (55,320)
  GROUP BY item_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) > 1
```

[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f56b/4)